# Can we communicate between two ng-app in two pages in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose, there are two html pages. Each html page has its own ng-app. If we want to send data from one ng-app of a html page to another ng-app of another html page, then how can we communicate between two ng-apps of two different pages.

I have two html pages app1.html and app2.html with its own ng-app. I am in a condition that I can not use layout or master page which share single ng-app and share data across multiple pages. Each html pages have one textbox. If I write something on each text boxes then it should be reflected to another textbox. Things to remember, those two pages are running on different tabs, I can't even use database,sessions,cookies to persist data.And, I can't even use parent/child relationship to get data from each other because if I use parent/child relationship of DOM, parent should exist to run child page.

Comment: This question is too broad. You should show what you have tried and what problems you encountered because there are different ways to do it, and many answers could be considered correct. We prefer questions that are specific to code you have written, but you can't quite get to work. Most questions should show the code you have used.

Comment: These apps are presumably in different browser tabs or windows? The only way they could directly communicate is if one app created the window in which the other app resides and provided callback functions to facilitate the communication. However, they could indirectly communicate through server API.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this all with drawbacks: localstorage, [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker), server message passing, etc.  This is too broad to answer as is.

Comment: @JCFord This is almost the exact use case for SharedWorker.  The hurdle is browser support.

Comment: If it's on the same domain, you can catch the events and know every changes inside your localstorage. 
But yes, there is many solutions like services, localstorage, third party API...

Comment: The only correct answer to your question: "Yes" and nothing else said.  Some clues for the implied question of "how": sockets, webRTC, the aforementioned LocalStorage, cookies, IE has a mechanism for communicating between parent/child pages ... there are many ways to do what you're asking, but it can be done.

Comment: I have two html pages app1.html and app2.html with its own ng-app. I am in a condition that I can not use layout or master page which share single ng-app and share data across multiple pages. Each html pages have one textbox. If I write something on each text boxes then it should be reflected to another textbox. Things to remember, those two pages are running on different tabs, I can't even use database,sessions,cookies to persist data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very naive implementation of sharing data between tabs/windows/whatever in a browser context using [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker).  Bear in mind, that this will only work within **one** browser context so data will not be replicated between tabs if you have both Firefox **and** Chrome open, but will be replicated across all open tabs in Firefox **or** Chrome.  To accomplish that you would have to do something server side.

### Demo

[image: Angular SharedWorker Demo]

### `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="hvApp">

<head>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <main ng-controller="hvCtrl as $ctrl">
        <h1>Shared Worker Test</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.hvText" ng-change="$ctrl.hvChange()">
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

### `/src/index.js`

```
/*jslint browser:true, esversion:6, devel:true*/
/*global angular*/
(function () {
    angular
        .module("hvApp", [])
        .service("hvShared", function ($rootScope) {
            let worker = new SharedWorker("src/shared-worker.js");
            this.notify = function (message) {
                worker.port.postMessage(message);
            };
            worker.port.onmessage = function (message) {
                console.log(`Heard: ${message}`);
                $rootScope.$broadcast("message", message.data);
            };
        })
        .controller("hvCtrl", function ($scope, hvShared) {
            let $ctrl = this;
            $ctrl.hvText = "Hello";

            $scope.$on("message", function (evt, message) {
                $scope.$applyAsync(function () {
                    $ctrl.hvText = message;
                });
            });

            $ctrl.hvChange = function () {
                hvShared.notify($ctrl.hvText);
            };
        });
}());
```

### `/src/shared-worker.js`

```
/*jslint worker:true, esversion:6, devel:true*/
let connections = [];

self.addEventListener("connect", (e) => {
    let port = e.ports[0];

    connections.push(port);

    port.addEventListener("message", (eMessage) => {
        console.log(eMessage);
        connections.forEach((p) => {
            p.postMessage(eMessage.data);
        });
    });

    port.start();
});
```